# Safely getting the next element of a list

Tags: haskell, circular-list

I'm looking for general review and improvements on this code that safely gets the next element of a list (and wraps to the first element if you exceed the list). It just seems a little excessive for how simple of a task it is.
It should also be noted that this function will only work for lists that do not contain duplicate elements. Unless I modify it to take index numbers instead, I can't see that restriction changing. If length list < 2, it will return Nothing.

```
nextElem :: Eq e => e -> [e] -> Maybe e
nextElem e xs = nextElem' e (shiftList e xs)
    where
        shiftList e xs = let (ya, yb) = break (== e) xs in yb ++ ya
        nextElem' _ []      = Nothing
        nextElem' _ (x : [])= Nothing
        nextElem' e (x : xs)
            | x == e    = Just (head xs)
            | otherwise = nextElem' e xs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using functions out of `base` you can implement this as a fairly readable one-liner.

```
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)

nextElem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe a
nextElem e xs = listToMaybe . drop 1 . dropWhile (/= e) $ xs ++ (take 1 xs)
```

To break that down, since the list is supposed to be "circular" we safely pop the first element off the front of `xs` with `take 1` (we either get the first element, or an empty list) and append that to the back of `xs` to get the wrapping property. (As an aside, this is complicated a small amount by being efficient, an equally correct solution to having a circular list would be `xs ++ xs`, but that would end up checking the entire list for equality twice if `e` isn't present.)

Next we drop all elements from the front of the list that are not equal to `e`, which either produces the empty list if the element isn't found, or the first tail of the list fronted by `e`, i.e., `(e:...)`, so we use `drop 1` as a safe version of `tail` (to again handle the case of an empty list) and end up with a list where the head element is our answer. Then `listToMaybe` produces `Just` the first element of the list, or `Nothing` if the list is empty.

In principle this isn't much different from your original solution, I've just shrink-wrapped it down to the constituent pieces and arranged control through function composition.

Comment: Ha. I didn't think that this could be shrunk down to a single line. I'd "staircase" it for readability, but I still like this answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to do the same thing in two different ways.

To detect the case where `e` is not in `xs`, you should check whether `yb` is empty.  (If that's what you were trying to do with `nextElem' _ (x : [])= Nothing` then you should note that it doesn't do that.)  I'm not sure what the purpose of the `otherwise` case is.  If `break` didn't find any element equal to `e`, recursion won't find it, either.  Therefore, a simpler solution would be

```
nextElem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe a
nextElem e xs
  | null match = Nothing
  | null rest  = Just (head xs)
  | otherwise  = Just (head rest)
  where
    (skip, match) = break (== e) xs
    rest = tail match
```

What is the expected result for `nextElem something [something]` — a one-element  list that happens to contain the element you are looking for?  I believe you would produce `Nothing`.  I would have expected `something` instead.  If you want to preserve the original behavior, where `nextElem 'a' "a"` produces `'a'`, then you could insert

```
nextElem e [_] = Nothing
```

as a special case to this solution.

Comment: I think you're confused on a couple points. The function returns the next element of a list, following `e`. The first `where` binding is a function that splits the list, and puts the given element at the start, and wraps the rest to the end. I wouldn't say that it's circular, as it's only ever called once; the list it produces is still linear. The `(x:[]) = Nothing` line ensures that the list is at least 2 elements long via pattern matching. The result of `nextElem 1 [5,3,9,1,6,8]` would be `Just 6`. It works exactly as intended, it's just long, and as you pointed out,

Comment: the wrapping is only required if the given element is the last on the list. It's wasteful, but otherwise I would have to check if `e == last xs`. I remember thinking that there was something wrong with that method, but I could have just underthought it.